# Never listen to your parents

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, music

I am a rock but never roll
No need to be a death toll
I can fly, yet I can't swim.
I am fly, but can not fly.
Space can not contain me,
But i'm smaller than a hedgehog.
Silly, scratching your head like a monkey
all these sentences are in the smoke
Wondering what am I?
Sometimes you just need to open your eye.

hint 1 :

> for those who didn't get it yet, the first sentence is just to introduce the topic of the riddle, and the answer is not Led Zeppelin

Hint 2 :

> The lord isn't with us anymore

What/who/where is the answer to that riddle?

Comment: Nope sorry, correcting

Comment: Something makes me think of Led Zeppelin.

Comment: It is a good point, I've edited a bit, it might not be so easy without google actually.

Comment: It's probably obvious, but the first line sounds like a reference to Led Zeppelin's Stairway to Heaven. The music tag and the title also seem to allude to "classic" rock, the kind of thing that, stereotypically, our parents would listen to. "I am fly" sounds like a reference to Pretty Fly for a White Guy. "Sometimes you just need to open your eye" might be a reference to Queen's Bohemian Rhapsody: "Open your eyes / And see". I don't know how to integrate these into a cohesive whole, though.

Comment: You're on the right way, but I'm not looking for multiple bands.

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Do you mean you're looking for a single band, then?

Comment: Yeh, but is it right to keep it in comments? it might spoil no?

Comment: I can't make it work, but Beatles is the vibe I'm getting

Comment: Are these references to lyrics, songs, or albums?? Getting plenty of ideas but not sure what level needs to tie them together.

Comment: They all most likely refer to a song, but you can relate some of these to albums too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the hints, I think the answer is obviously

> Deep Purple

**NOTES FROM THE ASKER** : this is the intended answer, you can find in spoilers both the original answer and the Asker's idea.

I am a rock but never roll

> Deep Purple in Rock

I can fly, yet I can't swim.

> Bird Has Flown
>  AUTHOR IDEA : Bird has flown / flight of the rat

Space can not contain me

> Child in Time
>  AUTHOR IDEA : Child in time, Fireball (the album cover)

all these sentences are in the smoke

> ... on the Water

Wondering what am I?

> Who Do We Think We Are?

Sometimes you just need to open your eye.

> Demon's Eye
>  AUTHOR IDEA : When a blind man cries

**Last lines (filled by author)**

I am fly, but can not fly.

> AUTHOR IDEA : Anyone's Daughter

But i'm smaller than a hedgehog.

> AUTHOR IDEA : flight of the rat

Silly, scratching your head like a monkey

> AUTHOR IDEA : bananas

Reason for hint 2 :

> Jon Lord, who was a member of Deep Purple died in 2012

Comment: That is it, but could you develop for each line? each line refers a song, or if you don't find the song an album.

Comment: Can't you fill the last lines before I accept your answer? :(

Comment: I have no idea for the other lines, sorry.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer and fill the blank spaces so I can accept with all the lines?

Comment: No problem, please edit.

Comment: My first thought was Deep Purple but at the time you'd asked us not to use Google so I assumed it would be more apparent to those who aren't familiar with their discography

Answer (score 10):

Answer:

> The Kinks

Reason:

I am a rock but never roll

> I'm On An Island

No need to be a death toll

> One Of The Survivors

I can fly, yet I can't swim.

> (Wish I Could Fly Like) Superman- "I'd like to fly but I can't even swim"

I am fly, but can not fly.

> Waterloo Sunset- "Millions of people swarming like flies 'round Waterloo underground"

Space can not contain me,

> In A Space

But i'm smaller than a hedgehog.

> Tin Soldier Man

Silly, scratching your head like a monkey

> Apeman

all these sentences are in the smoke

> Big Black Smoke

Wondering what am I?
Sometimes you just need to open your eye.

> Lola

Comment: Wow, I must agree that this fit the lines way more than I expected O_o. But this is not the band I'm looking for, Still +1 though, and if noone comes with the one I've thought about I think I will accept your answer cause it fits all the lines.

Answer (score 7):

You're

> **stoned as a shrimp.**

No need to be a death toll

> Marijuana is rarely lethal

I can fly, yet I can't swim.
I am fly, but can not fly.

> "Don't drink and drive, when you can smoke and fly!"

Space can not contain me,

> Out-of-body experience

all these sentences are in the smoke

> Well, duh

Comment: Haha, it is really fun, but don't fit the lines as I wanted ! Really imaginative tho, get my +1

Answer (score 5):

> The answer is The Beatles

I couldn´t figure it out the entire problem, but I think it's "this" band because:

I am a rock but never roll

> I think this is just like the Walrus song, where the lyrics are just complicated. Basically you are saying that they are a rock band.

No need to be a death toll

> Paul McCartney and Ringo are still alive?

I can fly, yet I can't swim.

I am fly, but can not fly.

> They were 2 of the 4 members of the band, but without the other one The Beatles are not, ah, The Beatles.

But i'm smaller than a hedgehog.

> Beatle

all these sentences are in the smoke

> Reason why I think this is about Beatles, this makes the whole text more complicated when maybe there is no reason to be.

I really don't know if it's them, but since I can't comment I decided to give it a try :)

Comment: _No need to be a death toll_ could be a reference to Let it Be, and _space can not contain me_ could be a reference to Across the Universe, and _Silly, scratching your head like a monkey_ could be referencing everbody's got something to hide except for me and my monkey

Comment: It fits a bit less than emdaniel's answer and some lines are not fitting that much, yet it is a good idea but not the band i'm looking for. +1 still

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer I know that some lines not fit that well, but in the end of the day, if your band was Beatles, everything based on the Walrus song wouldn't make sense anyway :)    Now I'm curious about this band that no one figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Could be

> Memory

the answer to this riddle?

I am a rock but never roll

> Memory could be Rock.. but obiouvsly never rolls...

I can fly, yet I can't swim.

> For sure with memory we could fly into our thoughts.. but it can't swim

I am fly, but can not fly.

> Exist RAM for Pc... but it can't fly really ehh

Space can not contain me

> Our memory is infinity

But i'm smaller than a hedgehog.

> The part of our brains that interest on memory is very little

Sorry for my english, I hope everyone understands.

Comment: Sorry... it is my first time and I don't know how to do this

Comment: Please use ">!" when posting answers so you do not spoil it!

Comment: Hi, you mean to develop my ansewer I need to use >! ?